# How to throttle throughput of a Quarkus reactive messaging stream

Tags: java, java-stream, quarkus, reactive-streams, mutiny

I'm using Quarkus 1.13.7 and smallrye reactive messaging to consume a Kafka topic and for each message making an HTTP request to an external component that impose a throughput limit of requests (eg. : 30 requests/second).

The idea is to call the external component as fast as possible to reach its maximum capacity but blocking the stream when the throughput limit is reached in a defined time window. Reaching maximum capacity would require to add concurrency using `@Blocking(ordered = false)` annotation, as a unique request can be a bit long.

But how I can throttle the stream when the limit throughput is reached ?

Is there a way to throttle a Multi stream, for example adding a mutiny operator on that stream, like what exists in [Akka Stream lib](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/throttle.html) ?

I know Akka is interoperable with Mutiny using Java 9 Reactive Streams interface but as Akka is not fully open source any more and as I would avoid thread switch complexity between Akka thread pool and Quarkus thread pool, this is not a option.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve this would be to assign a custom worker pool with max concurrency to your `@Blocking` annotation. It is described here: http://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/4.7.0/concepts/blocking/

Comment: thanks for your response. This would increase the concurrency only. My point is to maximize the message consumption using concurrency but throttle this consumption and block the stream if throughput limit is reached before continuing message consumption. How can I achieve this throttling (eg. : 30 messages/second) ?

Comment: Recent versions of Quarkus and Smallrye reactive messaging handle this by pausing/resuming the Kafka consumer polling depending on the downstream requests. But I think Quarkus 1.13.7 you are using had an early version of this mechanism which contained a bug.